# Problem with discord ballot box with check unicode emoji

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to react to a message with the ballot box with check, everything looked fine until I went on my phone and the emoji was a gray check instead. The weirdest thing is that you are able to react with the ballot box with check but it will come up as a second reaction making it look like there are two of the same emojis

```
check = '\N{BALLOT BOX WITH CHECK}'
await message.add_reaction(check)
```

The first reaction is from the bot. The second reaction is me.

[What it looks like on PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2Svl.png)

[What it looks like on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqBVg.jpg)

How would I go about getting the bot to react with the correct ballot box with check?

Comment: I guess you could try reacting with the unicode instead,`☑️`

Comment: what else do you have in code? Do you check if resonse is not from bot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different devices display emojis differently.
Thats why sometimes emotes doesn't look the same on pc and mobile.

To make sure you used the correct emote in your code, you can either

- use the emoji keyboard on your pc (`win + .`)
- copy it from sites like [emojipedia.org](https://emojipedia.org/check-box-with-check/)
- or write it in a discord channel with a blackslash before (`\:emojiname:` / `\☑️`) and copy the output